# Need help in making a php app connect to cleardb in heroku

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

I have recently decided to move to heroku from openshift, now i'm having a problem of not able to connect to cleardb mysql DB from heroku. need all of your help in this. Here is my php db config file. kindly let me know where im going wrong.

```
$url=parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));

  $server = $url["host"];
  $username = $url["user"];
  $password = $url["pass"];
  $db = substr($url["path"],1);
  $host= "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db";
  var_dump($host);
try {
    $conn=new PDO($host , $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
}
var_dump($conn);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($exc);
include 'classes.inc.php';

 echo "<br>".$db."<br>"; 
$project= new projecteg($conn);
```

the output of $conn gives this

```
object(PDO)#1 (0) { }
NULL
```

and i dont know how to enable the error output in heroku too.

Comment: Tip: Try to keep your include files named `.inc` and not `.inc.php` so they can't be executed accidentally.

Comment: @tadman any idea on how to connect to clearDB with heroku??